# Problema al generar archivo CSV

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de descargar un archivo CSV con registros generados en una clase. En el controlador tengo esto:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if (...) {
  (Hay varias rutinas porque es un controlador)
}


if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (isset($_POST['descargar']))) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=saldos.csv');
    $archivo = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fprintf($archivo, chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)); // Genera cabecera para Excel
    fputcsv($archivo, array('CODIGO', 'NOMBRE', 'SALDO'));

    $ctacteDAO = new CtacteDAO();
    $saldos = $ctacteDAO->saldos($_SESSION['periodo']);

        foreach ($saldosStud as $fila) {
        fputcsv($archivo, $fila);
    }
    fclose($archivo);
}
```

El archivo CSV se genera pero al final imprime esta línea:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\codigos\controlaReportes.php:31) in <b>C:\codigos\controlaReportes.php</b> on line <b>53</b><br />
```

La línea 31 tiene el `fputcsv($archivo, $fila);`
Y la línea 53 es el fin del documento PHP : `?>`

Al inicio del documento tiene esto:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Cuál es el problema que genera esto?

**ACTUALIZACION**

Al final del controlador tengo esto:

```
header('Location: index.php?action=principal');
```

Pues si en caso no se cumplen los *if* que redirigen los procesos se vaya al controlador principal.
Si quito este *header*, mi problema se resuelve. Pero ahora cómo reemplazo este *header* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se pueden enviar dos header del tipo `Content-Type` e imagino que de ahí viene el error, aunque tengo mis dudas que no tengas algun espacio a continuación del `?>` de la línea 53 de tu archivo `C:\codigos\controlaReportes.php`.

Prueba realizando lo siguiente:

1. Elimina el `?>` al final del archivo `C:\codigos\controlaReportes.php`. De hecho [está desaconsejado](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#22-files) usar el `?>` al final de cualquier archivo PHP (seguramente por eso que quizás te está ocurriendo ahora)
2. Mira de eliminar este header antes de llegar al tuyo:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

usando la función [header_remove()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header-remove.php) de este modo:

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (isset($_POST['descargar']))) {
    header_remove("Content-Type")
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
```

### Actualización

Dado el nuevo dato encontrado por el OP, donde ha descubierto que al final del controlador hay una cabecera más, a saber:

```
header('Location: index.php?action=principal');
```

la solución debería pasar por matar la ejecución del script justo después de esta línea:

```
fclose($archivo);
```

agregándole un `die();`o un `exit();` en la línea siguiente, de este modo:

```
fclose($archivo);
die();
```

Ya nos cuentas si te ha funcionado ahora de forma definitiva.

Comment: Modifiqué según tu respuesta pero todo sigue igual. Pero me di cuenta de un 'header('Location: index.php?action=principal');' que está al final. (Actualicé pregunta).

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, a ver si con eso ya lo consigues

Comment: Funciona con 'die()' aunque no me queda muy claro la razón.

Comment: La razón es porque así se detiene la ejecución en ese punto y tan solo manda lo que ya ha empezado a mandar, es decir, las otras cabeceras y el php://ouput